# Change drawable shape's color to given HEX

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have textView's that are created programmatically. They need to have different color values. I don't need animation or anything fancy, simply a given hex-value (eg FF00AB) to be applied to a textView's drawable shape:

---

**list_item.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner" />
```

---

**rounded_corner.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/dummyColorValue" />
</shape>
```

---

**ListAdapter.java**

```
   // Set Icon Color
   String color "FF00AB";
   Drawable iconDrawable = txtIcon.getBackground();
// how to change the <solid android:color>-Value of iconDrawable HERE??
```

Assume the hex-value of the variable color is dynamic.

**Q:** Is setColorFilter() the wrong approach or do I somehow have to convert the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few solutions that I came up with, it should help you one of them for sure:

**1**

```
 GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)btn.getBackground();
      bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

**2**

```
((GradientDrawable)someView.getBackground()).setColor(someColor);
```

**3**

```
   LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable) button.getBackground();
final GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable)
        bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.round_button_shape);
shape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

**4**

```
    example.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myshape);
GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) example.getBackground().getCurrent();
gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
gd.setCornerRadii(new float[]{30, 30, 30, 30, 0, 0, 30, 30});
gd.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"), 5, 6);
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: That's not an answer. Thats four! :) Thank you! Color.parseColor('#"+hexColor) worked!

Comment: Happy that I could help you :)